# Which function of V8 engine print informations to stdout？

Tags: v8, chromium

I add flag “--print-opt-code” to V8 engine, then v8 could print the compiled code to stdout. And now I what to print these information to specific files, then which function should I modify? 
Thank you very much~~

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `--redirect-code-traces-to=<filename>` ;-)

Generally speaking: follow the `FLAG_print_opt_code` through the source and see what it does.

Depending on where you run V8 (in d8? in Chrome? in node.js?), it might be easiest to just use shell redirection: `.../d8 test.js --print-opt-code > output.txt`